# doubt from apex developer guide

Tags: apex, soql

```
@isTest
private class HelloWorldTestClass {
    static testMethod void validateHelloWorld() {
       Book__c b = new Book__c(Name='Behind the Cloud', Price__c=100);
       System.debug('Price before inserting new book: ' + b.Price__c);
       insert b;
       // Retrieve the new book
       b = [SELECT Price__c FROM Book__c WHERE Id =:b.Id]; // this line
       System.debug('Price after trigger fired: ' + b.Price__c);
       System.assertEquals(90, b.Price__c);
    }
}


b = [SELECT Price__c FROM Book__c WHERE Id =:b.Id]
```

I think I can get the value of Price field by this SOQL ...But why it can be assigned to "b" ("b" is Book object..not the Price field).

Hope someone explain it.

Comment: Do you think you have missed a SOQL in your post? You have *//this line* in the SOQL above and then the latter SOQL looks exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Salesforce SOQL statements evaluate to a [list of sObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL.htm), [a single sObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_single_row.htm), or an [Integer for count](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_count.htm) method queries.

So even if you are Querying for a single field (other than Count) it will return the sObject(for your case it is Book).

Comment: I understand it...Then whats the purpose to indicate "Price__c"  in  "[SELECT Price__c FROM Book__c WHERE Id =:b.Id] "  if  SOQL statements evaluate to the object ?

Comment: @KazuSuzuki So that the price value field of the object can be checked in `System.assertEquals(90, b.Price__c);`.

Comment: SOQL evaluiates to an object or list of objects. Providing fields in the `SELECT` clause will provide each records returned data for those fields. Without providing the field to the query, trying to access the field would result in a null value. You should read the [SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm) specs, it goes into a lot of detail about each clause of a query.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to get the price directly you can do this:

```
Decimal price = [SELECT Price__c FROM Book__c WHERE Id =:b.Id].Price__c;
```

The SELECT query always results in Objects refer: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL.htm

Comment: Im so sorry..  i can understand what is the purpose of "Price__c " after "[Select~~~~.Id ]. "  

But Still i cant undestand what is the purpose  of  "Price__c " after Select ....if I get object ,  why i have to write "Price__c" just after select

Comment: I think Performance - there could be 40 fields on an object but you do not want to read them all from the database right? sometimes you also send them over the network .... so best is to get what you need.